# What is the order of field assignment when assigning compatible aggregate types

Tags: c

I've been looking for standardese on this all evening, with no luck. Perhaps I'm missing something!

In the following code example, is the copy into `uint32_t a` sequenced with the the copy into `uint32_t b` during the assignment `*one = *two`, or is this implementation defined?

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;
} x_t;

extern x_t volatile* get_volatile_x();
extern x_t const* get_const_x();

void foo()
{
  x_t volatile* one = get_volatile_x();
  x_t const* two = get_const_x();

  *one = *two;
}
```

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Vl0fdM

Here's and example where, with certain ARM flags, the load is done in the order [a, b], but the store is done in the order [b, a].

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
  volatile uint32_t a;
  volatile uint32_t b;
} x_t;

extern x_t* get_x();
extern x_t volatile* get_volatile_x();
extern x_t const* get_const_x();

void foo()
{
  x_t* one = get_x();
  x_t const* two = get_const_x();

  *one = *two;
}
```

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/FcRbhm

As a fun fact (I'm much more interested in the C question above than this detail) that this code will not compile with a C++ compiler. You'll get an error something like:

```
<source>:4:9: note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: 'this' argument has type 'volatile x_t', but method is not marked volatile
```

because it looks like C++ is expecting an `operator=()` which takes this as a `volatile`. Something like: https://godbolt.org/z/lt30dJ, although this isn't really quite right in C++ either.

Comment: Curious, why is the sequence of the assignment important?  Say it `a` then `b` today and `b` than `a` tomorrow, or 1 byte at a time in a random order, or  all 64-bits at once.  Perhaps you need `_Atomic` types.

Comment: gcc is emitting all 64 bits at once, most of the time. There's massaging that can be done to get it to not do that. There's also some oddities with struct packing when these structs are not packed (stick a u8, u32, and u64 in there). The order isn't really *important* to me, but I am curious if it is defined and/or what exactly (aggregate x) = (aggregate y) is defined to mean.

Comment: `_Atomic` does allow me to properly enforce that the write happens atomically when possible, so I've been using that for the small structs, but, using _Atomic in a c header with `static inline` functions makes including the C header into a C++ program sort of awkward.

Comment: I suspect the answer will go along the idea of the _abstract machine_ and the detail of your question is beyond what C specifies for that _abstract machine_, so a compliant compiler could  do just about any sequence before moving on to the next _sequence point_.  Good luck.

Comment: @chux: The sequence matters inside C because accessing a volatile object is  an observable effect, so an access to `a` followed by an access to `b` is different, inside C’s model, from an access to `b` followed by an access to `a`. The sequence matters outside C because these may be mapped to device control registers that need some value written to `a` as a parameter or data for a command initiated by a write to `b`.

Comment: @eric that's what I thought initially too, but the guarantees don't seem to be quite that strong. Volatile doesn't imply that a read or write will happen in a single instruction, just that it will always happen. gcc is emitting one 64 bit store for this code, so if these were two 32 bit registers, the code generated would look very funny (although I suspect the memory controller would do the right thing). Really need _Atomic to make the stronger guarantees, unless the order of assignment is actually specified for an aggregate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agree with [matters outside C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114057/what-is-the-order-of-field-assignment-when-assigning-compatible-aggregate-types?noredirect=1#comment93130150_53114057).  Inside C I see it matters, yet do not see the C specifies the order. Hmmm - that appears to be a point of your [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118285/2410359).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard does not define ordering for assignment of members within a structure when assigning a structure.

About assignment, C 2018 6.5.16.1 says only:

> 2 In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.
>
> 3 If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Examining the standard for all mentions of “member”, “struct”, or “structure” does not reveal anything that would impose any chronological ordering on the members within the assignment. (There is not even an explicit definition of what the value of a structure is; we are left to presume it is effectively an ordered tuple of the value of its members, or perhaps, from “a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members” in 6.7.2.1 6, that its value is a sequence of values of its members.)

Comment: That's about the same conclusion I drew, which leads me to ask, does a volatile struct really make any sense if the language doesn't actually tell you anything about what exactly side effects must be preserved when writing to it?